# how to read write labview network shared variable from c++

Tags: c++, labview

LabVIEW gives the possibility of sharing variables over the network. I would like to be able to read and set those variable from my C++ code. (I run under linux system)

I read there are some DLL API for communication but of course they do not fit my purpose.

I guess we the whole communication should be simply based on sockets and therefore I guess should be more than feasible from linux environment.

Does anyone have some information/ideas about this topic?

Comment: will LabVIEW and C++ code run on the same machine?

Comment: no... over the network... :( otherwhise i would have ben trying to use files as sudgested here:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596676/share-a-variable-between-c-and-labview

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Python code quacks, and C++ code runs

Comment: i just read my first value succesfully... i'm touched...;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not very easy to find it on the website but I have been pointed out to an official library, [NI LabWindows™/CVI™ 2009 Help - Network Variable Library](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051P-01/cvi/libref/cvinetwork_variable_library_function_tree/), that should do all the magic.

I haven't tested it yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like they only support interop with C++ on Windows.

You'd have to reimplement the entire crosstalk mechanism yourself, by reverse engineering their comms protocol. Not trivial!

Comment: yes... this is what i was thinking about... but i did not found anythink yet clear enought to understand where to start from! like a clear protocoll spec or the windows code for the dll :(

Comment: @Stefano: You'll also need to verify that their Terms Of Use cover this. It's clearly not how they want you to use the product.

Answer (score 0):

Having no way to implement LV shared variable protocol (as Tomalak's post says), your best bet to enable communication between both would be to

- use another messaging protocol, like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), and make bindings for LabVIEW.
- use raw TCP or UDP sockets, both being supported in LabVIEW and C++